# Groovy - recommended modifier order

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jls

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) defines a recommended order for class and method modifiers.

Does a similar convention exist for Groovy? For example, should it by `def static` or `static def`?

I already checked the [official style guide](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html) but did not find anything.

Comment: you mean define a static method or variable?

Comment: In my case, a static method, but I assume it should not matter.

Comment: just `static` should do `static main(args) { println args }` for example

Comment: Groovy is basically an extension of Java, just go with Java conventions when nothing is specified.